# Google spreadsheet script, Instance status after applying a formula on a large amount of data

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula

When I apply a Formula using google spreadsheet script on a large amount of data there is a processing time. how could I check that the processing is finished.
For example, if I use the code below on google spreadsheet script editor :

```js
ss.getRange("xxxx").setFormulas(formulasToApply); 
ss.getRange("xxxx").copyTo("YYYY");
ss.getRange("YYYY").copyTo("YYYY", {contentsOnly:true});
```

*** it's not a working code it's only an illustration ;)****

I have no data on my "YYYY" Range :(

Thanks,
*NB: If it's not clear i will add google spreadsheet example.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add [`SpreadsheetApp.flush()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush) to apply all spreadsheet changes immediately, it will allow you to use updated values right after it:

```
ss.getRange("xxxx").setFormulas(formulasToApply); 
ss.getRange("xxxx").copyTo("YYYY");

// apply all changes right now
SpreadsheetApp.flush();

// now can copy calculated formulas results
ss.getRange("YYYY").copyTo("YYYY", {contentsOnly:true});
```